# SQL - GET VALUE USING MAX

Tags: sql, oracle11g, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to get the AMOUNT_APP WHERE DATE _APP is the greatest value.

I wrote this query, but I am having troubles

```
SELECT AMOUNT_APP
FROM Payments_App
WHERE DATE_APP = MAX(DATE_APP)
```

I expect to get 5234.34

[My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06aDS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `order by` and `rownum`:

```
select pa.amount_app
from (select pa.*
      from payments_app
      order by date_app desc
     ) pa
where rownum = 1;
```

Or `keep` can be quite efficient:

```
select max(pa.amount_app) keep (dense_rank first order by date_app desc)
from payments_app;
```

Answer (score 0):

If we suppouse that DATE_APP is an attribute that you could find the most recently updated results.

> select **AMOUNT_APP** FROM Payments_App WHERE **DATE_APP** = (Select
>   MAX(**DATE_APP**) FROM Payments_App) ;